# Projective Space orientation

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to prove that the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^n$ is orientable is and only if $n$ is odd. To do that that, I have a hint,to prove that the antipodal map is orientation preserving if only if $n$ is odd, I've done that, but it don't know how to conclude the result.

Comment: How to you define $\mathbb P^n$?

Comment: Identifying antipodal points on the sphere...

Comment: What do you know about the orientability of the sphere?

Comment: I know that it is a orientable manifold...

Comment: So, what happens if you simply take the orientation of the sphere as orientation of the projective space?

Comment: @Phira what do you mean?

Comment: I think the word "plane" is misleading if we aren't talking about the 2-dimensional object; perhaps projective "space" would be a better term?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{O_p\}_{p \in S^n}$ be an orientation for $S^n$. If $\pi:S^n \rightarrow \mathbb P^{n}$ is the projection (a local diffeomorphism), then the idea is to define a basis $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$  of $T_q\mathbb P^{n}$ to be in $O_q'$ if $\pi_{*,p}^{-1}(b_1,\dots,b_n) \in O_p$ for any one of the two points $p$ in the fibre $\pi^{-1}(q)$.

You have already shown that this is well defined if $n$ is odd!

Comment: do you have a proof using differential forms aproach?

Comment: you mean providing a nowhere vanishing $n-$Form?

Comment: yes!! This exercise was in the context of differential forms.

Comment: You must show a nonwhere vanishing $n$-form: if you have $n$ tangent vectors at $q$, then you could push them up via $\pi^{-1}_{*,p}$ for the two points $p$. On $S^n$ there is a volume form - evaluate. This is well defined if $n$ is odd. (think about the pullback of the volumeform under the antipodal map)